# Find nearest values using SQL with date diff

Tags: sql, oracle

Simple example data for clarity:

```
PERSON_PINCODE

PERSON        START_DATE    END_DATE    PINCODE
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6059    
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6060  

PINCODE_VALUE

PINCODE START_DATE  END_DATE    VAR     VALUE
6059    01-04-11    30-06-11    3889    28.4
6059    01-07-11    30-09-11    3889    28.2
6059    01-10-11    31-12-11    3890    31.4
6060    01-04-11    30-06-11    3889    29.4
6060    01-07-11    30-09-11    3889    41.2
6060    01-10-11    31-12-11    3890    43.4

Output should be:
```

PERSON_PINCODE_VALUE

```
PERSON          START_DATE  END_DATE    PINCODE   VAR   VALUE  DIFF
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6059      3889  28.2   90 days
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6059      3890  31.4   1 day
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6060      3890  41.2   90 days
10023541700000  01-01-12    31-03-12    6060      3890  43.4   1 day
```

To get PERSON_PINCODE_VALUE,

do the following:

```
1) Take each row of PERSON_PINCODE and find PINCODE, START_DATE, END_DATE
2) For each PINCODE from step 1, find START_DATE, END_DATE, VAR, VALUE from PINCODE_VALUE
3) Associate all values from step 1 and step 2, on the basis of PINCODE, START_DATE and END_DATE
4) If in step 3, we do NOT get exact PINCODE, START_DATE and END_DATE for each VAR from step 2, find nearest prior START_DATE for remaining VAR
5) Associate values from step 4 with DIFF as  PERSON_PINCODE.START_DATE - PINCODE_VALUE.END_DATE
```

Comment: Please share the script you tried

Comment: For simplicity, can you renumber all the people 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. Also, for person `10025868900000` how do you get that start and end date and why do you have duplicate rows with different `pincode`s?

Comment: Also for person `10023541700000` if you do `DATE '2012-01-01' - DATE '2011-07-01'` you get 184 days - how do you get a diff of 90 days?

Comment: @MT0 - ah, you are right for date difference.

Comment: @MT0 - we have duplicate rows for different pinches because of different VAR and VALUE.

Comment: Also for person `10000435700000` why is it not matched with this row `6075    01-01-12    31-03-12    3893    28.4` which is much closer in dates?

Comment: @MT0 - for 10000435700000, you need to also check the VAR, the VAR is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113730/discussion-between-dang-and-mt0).

Comment: @dang please pick one or two lines of the table and write out the logic of why they give the output they do in plain English so you can fully explain the logic as your comments do not correlate with the logic given in the middle of the OP.

Comment: @MT0 - can you come on chat?

Comment: @MT0 - I have updated example. I will add text.

Comment: @dang Chat blocked by firewall.

Comment: @MT0 - added algorithmic steps

Comment: Please re-check the result. `select distinct PERSON_PINCODE.START_DATE - PINCODE_VALUE.END_DATE from PERSON_PINCODE cross join PINCODE_VALUE order by 1;` gives 1, **93** and 185; how you get the **90** days difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a "more conventional" approach with a join of all rows and filtering the best match using the `ROW_NUMBER`

```
with hlpr as (
select pp.PERSON, pp.START_DATE, pp.END_DATE, pp.PINCODE,
pv.START_DATE PV_START_DATE, pv.END_DATE PV_END_DATE,
pv.VALUE, pv.VAR,
pp.START_DATE - pv.END_DATE as diff,
row_number() over(partition by pp.PERSON, pp.START_DATE, pp.END_DATE, pp.PINCODE, pv.VAR 
   order by  pp.START_DATE - pv.END_DATE) as rn 
from PERSON_PINCODE pp
join PINCODE_VALUE pv on pp.PINCODE = pv.PINCODE
where pp.START_DATE >= pv.END_DATE /* prior PV only */
)
select /*+ PARALLEL(5) */ PERSON, START_DATE, END_DATE, PINCODE,  VAR,VALUE, DIFF
from hlpr
where rn = 1
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

gives

```
PERSON         START_DATE        END_DATE             PINCODE        VAR      VALUE       DIFF
-------------- ----------------- ----------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
10023541700000 01.01.12 00:00:00 31.03.12 00:00:00       6059       3889       28,2         93 
10023541700000 01.01.12 00:00:00 31.03.12 00:00:00       6059       3890       31,4          1 
10023541700000 01.01.12 00:00:00 31.03.12 00:00:00       6060       3889       41,2         93 
10023541700000 01.01.12 00:00:00 31.03.12 00:00:00       6060       3890       43,4          1
```

I'd prefer this solution if the query has a large number of attributes (as the ordering logic is concentrated in one place).

Only for a large data sets I would use the GROUP BY approach from @MT0 as the `SORT GROUP BY`in general performs better than the `WINDOW SORT`.

Here the sample data

```
create table PERSON_PINCODE as 
select '10023541700000' PERSON,  to_date('01-01-12','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('31-03-12','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 6059 PINCODE from dual union all
select '10023541700000' PERSON,  to_date('01-01-12','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('31-03-12','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 6060 PINCODE from dual
;

create table PINCODE_VALUE as
select 6059 PINCODE,  to_date('01-04-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('30-06-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3889 VAR, 28.4 VALUE from dual union all
select 6059 PINCODE,  to_date('01-07-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('30-09-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3889 VAR, 28.2 VALUE from dual union all
select 6059 PINCODE,  to_date('01-10-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('31-12-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3890 VAR, 31.4 VALUE from dual union all
select 6060 PINCODE,  to_date('01-04-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('30-06-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3889 VAR, 29.4 VALUE from dual union all
select 6060 PINCODE,  to_date('01-07-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('30-09-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3889 VAR, 41.2 VALUE from dual union all
select 6060 PINCODE,  to_date('01-10-11','dd-mm-rr') START_DATE, to_date('31-12-11','dd-mm-rr') END_DATE, 3890 VAR, 43.4 VALUE from dual;
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work, because if I have multiple VAR associated with each PINCODE, it just assigns one VAR. Also, if there is an exact match between date, lag is being calculated as 1 or 89 whereas it should be 0.

Comment: @dang Edited to the new condiotions

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   p.person,
         p.start_date,
         p.end_date,
         p.pincode,
         v.var,
         MAX( v.value )
                  KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ABS( v.start_date - p.start_date ) )
                  AS value,
         DECODE(
           MIN( ABS( v.start_date - p.start_date ) ),
           0, 0,
           MIN( ABS( p.start_date - v.end_date ) )
                  KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ABS( p.start_date - v.start_date ) )
         ) AS diff
FROM     Person_Pincode p
         INNER JOIN
         Pincode_Value v
         ON ( p.pincode = v.pincode )
GROUP BY p.person,
         p.start_date,
         p.end_date,
         p.pincode,
         v.var;
```

Comment: Nice solution with `KEEP`

Comment: the value for VAR is wrong, because you are using MAX value, this won't work. Also, diff is wrong.

Comment: @dang Just saying that its wrong is not constructive in fixing the issue. Please tell me **why** it is wrong - possibly with some example calculations to illustrate the issue (and, if possible, what could be done to correct it).

Comment: @MT0 - sorry let me explain. v.value is NOT getting associated of the respective v.var. v.value is of different VAR. In my above table, add multiple VAR and try it out.

Comment: @dang - Updated, you can try adding `ROWNUM` to the `ORDER BY` clause of the analytic functions - it will then get the `var` and `value` for the only first row it finds which is closest to the date (rather than considering the `MAX()` over all rows with that similar difference).

Comment: @MT0 - right now, the count of values using your query is equal to PERSON_PINCODE, but the count should be MORE, because for each PINCODE, start_date and end_date, you can have multiple VAR & Values. For ex. PINCODE = 6073, has VAR - 3890, 3892, 3893, 3894, so it would be 4 times.

Comment: @dang - Updated but untested - I've included `v.var` in the `GROUP BY` clause so you should get one row per person per var.

Comment: @MT0 - nope, still issues with the output, not right.